# Prove the parameter shift rule in case of generator is Pauli matrix

Tags: machine-learning

I'm studying the parameter shift rule and got stuck when doing an example with Pauli operators in https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00745.

With $f=e^{-i\mu\frac{\sigma_i}{2}}$, $\partial_\mu f=\frac{(-i\sigma_i)}{2}f=(-\frac{1}{2}if)\sigma_i$    (1).

Because $\frac{1}{2}\sigma_i$ has eigenvalues $\pm\frac{1}{2}$, so $r=1/2$ and $s=\frac{\pi}{4r}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

$\rightarrow\partial_\mu f=\frac{1}{2}(f(\mu+\frac{\pi}{2})-f(\mu-\frac{\pi}{2}))$

$
=\frac{1}{2}(e^{-i(\mu+\frac{\pi}{2})\frac{\sigma_i}{2}}-e^{-i(\mu-\frac{\pi}{2})\frac{\sigma_i}{2}})
$

$
=\frac{1}{2}(e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_i)}-e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_i)}) f(\mu)
$

$
=-\frac{1}{2}i(2\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}\sigma_i)) f(\mu)=-\frac{1}{2}i(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\sigma_i) f(\mu)
$    (2)

The results from (1) and (2) seem to not be the same, I don't know what points I missed.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What are $r$ and $s$ here? It is also not always clear when you are saying $f(x)$ means $f$ is a function of $x$ versus $f$ is multiplied by $x$.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Thanks for the answer, seem to I be confused between these quantities in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two different quantities. Reading up on the parameter shift rule [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11184), you will see that the gradient of an **expectation value**
$f(\mu) = \langle \psi | \mathcal{G}^\dagger Q \mathcal{G} | \psi \rangle$ can be computed via
$$\partial_\mu f = r[ f(\mu+s) - f(\mu-s)] \ ,$$
where $s=\frac{\pi}{4r}$, if $\mathcal{G}(\mu) = e^{-i\mu G}$ when $G$ has at most two eigenvalues $\pm r$.

You are confusing the expectation value $f(\mu)$ with the gate $\mathcal{G}(\mu)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I have focused so much about the gate $\mathcal{G}(\mu)$ and forgot the expectation value, maybe this case will be more complex.